# Steps need to taken care when entire farm is down in SP 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, server-farm, farm, sharepoint-farm

Recently came across the situation that entire farm is down and came to know that 
service is unavailable.

- IIS reset did not help.
- App Pool restart also done.
- Server space was cleaned and had enough space in drive too.
- Server reboot didnt either.

Any ideas for resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Farm service account that used to host the application was locked due to which multiple services was in stopped mode.

After all the initial troubleshooting mentioned in the question.

It's with the services in the Services.msc that helped narrow down, there were eight services that we using this account and that was in stopped mode.

[image]

Earlier could not start this service manually and received an error message that it failed to start due to logon services failed .

Post that checked that service account and unlocked the account in AD.

After that these services started , then it worked seamlessly.

Sharing with community  so that anyone having similar experience can be aware and save their day.